# GetElementById not able to find a dropdown list in HTML for VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba

I'm working on a new macro that extracts info from a web page, and it needs to fill in some information first. One of those is a drop-down list. So currently my code opens up both pages needed and tries to track the dropdown list, but it doesn't find it. Is it because of the id name? Here are my code and an HTML snippet.

It's my first time working with web pages in VBA so any advice is welcome.

[screen cap of the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oiIo.png)

```html
<FORM NAME="queryform" METHOD="POST" ACTION="/phpwebedit/webedit/main.php?WEB_QUERY_NAME=MACH%20TYPE%20CYCLE%20TIME">
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="WQSUBMIT_WEB_QUERY_NAME" VALUE="MACH TYPE CYCLE TIME">
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="WQSUBMIT_QUERY_FORM" VALUE="1">
<TABLE class="List" align="center" id="querybox" >
<CAPTION>Mach Type Cycle Time Report Query Form </CAPTION><TR><TD width="100%" ><TABLE width="100%" >
<TR>
  <TD></TD>
  <TH>MACH_TYPE</TH>
  <TH>TRANS_START_DATE</TH>
  <TH>CYCLE_TIME_PERCENT</TH>
</TR>
<TR><TD>Lower Bound or Exact Match</TD>
  <TD>
<SELECT NAME='TOP_MACH_TYPE' id='TOP_MACH_TYPE'  ><OPTION VALUE="APXRPR">APXRPR</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="BAPX">BAPX</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="BEAD">BEAD</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="BEDRPR">BEDRPR</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="CAL">CAL</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="CALRPR">CALRPR</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="EXT">EXT</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="HFPLT4">HFPLT4</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="MIX">MIX</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="PAINT">PAINT</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="PLY">PLY</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="PLYRPR">PLYRPR</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="PRS">PRS</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="RAW">RAW</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="SHR">SHR</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="SLIT">SLIT</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="SOLRPR">SOLRPR</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="STLRPR">STLRPR</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="SWRPR">SWRPR</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="TRDRPR">TRDRPR</OPTION>
</SELECT><INPUT type='hidden' name='COMPARISON_TOP_MACH_TYPE' value='='>
```

```
Sub prueba2()
Const url As String = "http://clstrace2/phpwebedit/webedit/main.php? 
WEB_QUERY_NAME=MACH TYPE CYCLE TIME"
Dim ie As Object
Dim base As Object
Dim htmlDoc As Object
Dim mach As Object
Dim tipo As String

tipo = "HFPLT4"
Set base = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
base.Visible = True
base.navigate "http://clstrace2//cmt/"

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate URL
On Error Resume Next
Do
Loop Until ie.readyState = 4
Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3))

Set htmlDoc = ie.document
On Error Resume Next
Set mach = htmlDoc.getElementById("TOP_MACH_TYPE") 
On Error GoTo 0

If Not mach Is Nothing Then
mach.selectedIndex = 4
Call TriggerEvent(htmlDoc, mach, "change")
Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1))
Else
MsgBox "there's no list"
Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Your id is correct. However, I cannot reach that url. Is it public? Is it correct? Also, are you getting any error messages? Remove that unclosed on error resume next and the closed On Error Resume Next pair.

Comment: The URL is private, but I can access it from my pc. I removed both, and an error 430 came up ( class doesn't support automatization).  But I've seen people use this kind of code for dropdown lists.

Comment: on which line does this occur.?

Comment: It happens in the loop-until-ready section. I deleted it, and now I'm getting a 462 error when running the code. This new error occurs when I set the HTML doc as an internet explorer document.

Answer (score 0):

Since the site is not accessible to us, I'll give an example that breaks your problem down to the core. So I have only programmed the waiting for the dropdown and calling the 4th entry.

If that doesn't work, then maybe the dropdown is in a frame or iFrame. If it is in a frame, it's another HTML document that needs to be accessed.

I don't understand the URL. It doesn't contain a top-level domain and the parameter list is also in the wrong format. But if the page is accessed in IE as you expect it to be, then everything is ok.

The following code calls the page in IE and then tries to access the dropdown. I have included a timeout that takes effect if the dropdown is not found within 10 seconds. You can change the time as you like.

I assume that you have copied the subroutine `TriggerEvent()` into your module.

```
Sub prueba2()

Const url As String = "http://clstrace2/phpwebedit/webedit/main.php?WEB_QUERY_NAME=MACH TYPE CYCLE TIME"

Dim ie As Object
Dim mach As Object
Dim timeoutStart As Double

  Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  ie.Visible = True
  ie.navigate url
  
  timeoutStart = Timer
  Do
    On Error Resume Next
    Set mach = ie.document.getElementById("TOP_MACH_TYPE")
    On Error GoTo 0
  Loop Until Not mach Is Nothing Or Timer - timeoutStart > 10 'Timeout in seconds
  
  If Not mach Is Nothing Then
    mach.selectedIndex = 4
    Call TriggerEvent(ie.document, mach, "change")
  Else
    MsgBox "there's no list"
  End If
End Sub
```

### Edit 1:

Code to save the HTML code of the page:

```
Sub SaveHTML()

Const path As String = "E:\" 'Don't forget the backslash at the end
Const url As String = "http://clstrace2/phpwebedit/webedit/main.php?WEB_QUERY_NAME=MACH TYPE CYCLE TIME"

Dim ie As Object
Dim nodeHtml As Object

  Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  ie.Visible = True
  ie.navigate url
  Do While ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 30)) 'Waiting with the crowbar for loading the whole page
  
  Set nodeHtml = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("html")(0)
  
  Close
  Open path & "clstrace2HTML.txt" For Output As #1
  Print #1, nodeHtml.outerHTML
  Close
  
  ie.Quit
End Sub
```

### Edit 2:

Save the static part of the page:

```
Sub SaveHtmlWithMsXml()

Const path As String = "E:\" 'Don't forget the backslash at the end
Const url As String = "http://clstrace2/phpwebedit/webedit/main.php?WEB_QUERY_NAME=MACH TYPE CYCLE TIME"

  With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp.6.0")
    .Open "GET", url, False
    .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:85.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/85.0"
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/plain"
    .send
    
    If .Status = 200 Then
      Close
      Open path & "clstrace2HTML.txt" For Output As #1
      Print #1, .responseText
      Close
    End If
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Zwenn, thanks for your help. This is a company's private URL, although I do have access from my pc, and I can extract the information manually through IE. I tried your code, but I get the "there's no list" message. I do not know about the frames.

Comment: Without a look to the page nobody can say more I think.

Comment: I could add a longer HTML snippet and a screen capture.

Comment: Yes, try that. Maybe someone will have another idea with further infos like that.

Comment: Ok, there's the updated version, and I added a screen cap of the website

Comment: Ok, that doesn't really help. I have edited my answer. Run the additional macro. It writes the HTML code of the downloaded page into a text file. Please make sure to adapt the path for this file to your environment. After IE says the page is loaded, I have added another 30 seconds to make sure everything is loaded. So it takes some time. Then open the generated text file and search first for the desired id of the dropdown `TOP_MACH_TYPE`. I assume that nothing will be found. Then search for `frame`. If you find `frame`, we can take a closer look.

Comment: I get an error (462) at the "set node HTML" line. I think the website is the problem, it may be too old or built specifically in a way that it doesn't allow it to be mined.

Comment: Mysterious. Try to save the static part of the page with the VBA code in `Edit 2` of my answer and look what is inside the file.